# MarkLogic XQuery xdmp:save/xdmp:quote indent-untyped option

Tags: save, xquery, indentation, quote, marklogic

Has anyone used this option before? I do not believe that this feature is working how it should be as I am failing to compile my code once I have inserted this as a option.

The problem I am trying to achive is to pretty print a document which has no namespace, due to the document not having a namespace I can not validate it against a schema therefore the  option does not work. The option  seems to be the correct way to go about this reading the documentation but I can not seem to get it to work.

Would be good to hear if anyone else has had issues with this option aswell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the Server are you using?

Default serialization changed for indenting of typed and untyped XML in earlier versions of 4.2 (around 4.2-3).

http://docs.marklogic.com/4.2doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/4.2doc/xml/relnotes/chap4.xml%2340996

Comment: I am using 4.2-4, using the variable:  declare option xdmp:output "indent-untyped=yes" ;  fixed my problem. Thanks.